# OpenCV Python: Blur image using trackbar

Tags: python, opencv, trackbar

I'd like to control the blur of an image by using a trackbar. The given MWE imports a picture with a trackbar that sets the aperture linear size (`ksize`) which has to be one or a positive odd number. Strangely `getTrackbarPos` returns a negative number which makes it necesarry to multiply `ksize` by -2 and subtract 1. Inside an infinite loop the image gets blurred and displayed.

```
import cv2

# Callback function for trackbar
def on_change(self):
    pass

# Reads image with 0 as GRAY and 1 as BGR
img = cv2.imread('example.JPG', 0)

# Creates window
cv2.namedWindow('Image')

# Creates Trackbar with slider position and callback function
low_k = 1  # slider start position
high_k = 21  # maximal slider position
cv2.createTrackbar('Blur', 'Image', low_k, high_k, on_change)

# Infinite loop
while(True):
    ksize = cv2.getTrackbarPos('ksize', 'Image')  # returns trackbar position
    ksize = -2*ksize-1  # medianBlur allows only odd ksize values

    # Blures input image
    median = cv2.medianBlur(img, ksize)  # source, kernel size

    cv2.imshow('Image', median)  # displays image 'median' in window
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

By running this code a window opens with the desired trackbar on top of the input image. The slider start position is one as desired but by changing the silder's position there is no blur or any significant change to the displayed image.

The main question is why the returned trackbar position does not have any influence on `medianBlur()`. My first thought suggests a mistake either inside the `while` loop or the callback function.
Besides that I'd like to know why `getTrackbarPos` returns negativ numbers.

I am using Python 3.6 with Anaconda 1.9.2. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Normally you do the change of a variable on the callback function you passed to createTrackbar... but in any case, `cv2.getTrackbarPos('ksize', 'Image')` should be: `cv2.getTrackbarPos('Blur', 'Image')` to match the arguments you supplied in the createTrackbar part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getTrackbarPos` arguments expects the name of the trackbar and the name of the window. You are creating the trackbar with the name `Blur` and reading as `ksize`, change

```
ksize = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Blur', 'Image')
```

to

```
ksize = cv2.getTrackbarPos('ksize', 'Image')
```

or change the other way around (the `createTrackbar` method).

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you can also update `ksize` on the `on_change` callback.

As a side note, you also need to adjust the way you treat odd values, if the track bar position is 1, the ksize ends up as -3

Comment: This solved the problem! I am aware of your side note as it is only for testing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad to help!